# Prevent div height to be "0"

Tags: html, css

I have this html structure:-

```
<div id="middle">
    <div id="category_container_1" class="category_container" rel="1">
        <div class="big"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/images/1-big.png"></div>
        <div class="small"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/images/1-6.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="category_container_2" class="category_container" rel="2">
        <div class="big"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/images/1-big.png"></div>
        <div class="small"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/images/1-6.png"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS is like this:-

```
#middle {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-bottom:70px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    overflow:auto;
}
.category_container{
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    clear:both;
}
```

I set .category_container to have height: auto, since the contents inside will expand the div downward, and html appearance works fine.

However, when viewing in chrome, it shows category_container_1, category_container_2 both are 960px x 0px, it is due to height: auto in CSS (I tried to change it to 100px and it shows on chrome as 960px x 100px).

In this case, how can I make the div in chrome to be 960px x actual px for these divs?

Comment: I'm seeing normal heights http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/M6TqB/. About 659x50.

Comment: a demo is here: http://demo.nevertoolate.com.hk/lee125/

Comment: I found the answer. Since the contents inside are floating left, I need to add display:inline-block to the .category_container so that it will display normally. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use `min-height:` in your css and give it a value higer than 0

Answer (score 1):

Try using min-height

```
.category_container{
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height : valueabove 0 ;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since the content will change dinamically, I guess you could try:

```
#middle {
position:relative;
width:100%;
max-width: 960px;    
margin: 0px auto;
padding-bottom:70px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
overflow:hidden; min-height:1px;
```

Comment: but with overflow:hidden you should not need the min-height, probably